# Unknown column 't.dst_enabled' in 'field list' after EE 2.7.2 Upgrade

Tags: ee2, entries, ee2-upgrades, ssl

Okay this one is totally nuts, I've spent all day trying to nail this one.

I've attempting to go from EE 2.5.5 to 2.7.2, but after the upgrade, I'm getting the following error on some pages:

```
    Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 't.dst_enabled' in 'field list'

SELECT t.entry_id, t.channel_id, t.forum_topic_id, t.author_id, t.ip_address, t.title, t.url_title, t.status, t.dst_enabled, t.view_count_one, t.view_count_two, t.view_count_three, t.view_count_four, t.allow_comments, t.comment_expiration_date, t.sticky, t.entry_date, t.year, t.month, t.day, t.edit_date, t.expiration_date, t.recent_comment_date, t.comment_total, t.site_id as entry_site_id, w.channel_title, w.channel_name, w.channel_url, w.comment_url, w.comment_moderate, w.channel_html_formatting, w.channel_allow_img_urls, w.channel_auto_link_urls, w.comment_system_enabled, m.username, m.email, m.url, m.screen_name, m.location, m.occupation, m.interests, m.aol_im, m.yahoo_im, m.msn_im, m.icq, m.signature, m.sig_img_filename, m.sig_img_width, m.sig_img_height, m.avatar_filename, m.avatar_width, m.avatar_height, m.photo_filename, m.photo_width, m.photo_height, m.group_id, m.member_id, m.bday_d, m.bday_m, m.bday_y, m.bio, md.*, wd.* FROM exp_channel_titles  AS t LEFT JOIN exp_channels AS w ON t.channel_id = w.channel_id LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS wd ON t.entry_id = wd.entry_id LEFT JOIN exp_members  AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id LEFT JOIN exp_member_data    AS md ON md.member_id = m.member_id WHERE t.entry_id IN (27) ORDER BY t.sticky desc, t.entry_date desc, t.entry_id desc

Filename: modules/channel/mod.channel.php

Line Number: 297
```

I thought it was  a simple issue of an addon not being updated as dst_enabled has been removed since 2.6.

Now it get's weird.

I only get this error if I access the pages with a channel tag over SSL.

I've cut everything back to absolute bare bones, all addons, extensions, plugins and field types have been uninstalled and physically removed from the site. I've created a very basic template to reproduce the error:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" entry_id="27" limit="1" disable="categories|pagination|member_data|custom_fields|category_fields"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've also replaced all EE files with a fresh download in case a file was not replaced during the upgrade.

I've disabled htaccess, and reverted to stock EE config.

Running on PHP 5.4.19 and can reproduce it on different servers with entirely different configurations.

The really annoying thing is I've run into this issue before, took days to track it down but I didn't document the fix! Paying the price now :(

Comment: Why don't you just add the column in the table?

Comment: Well that column was removed in EE 2.6.0 when they implemented better DST handling. So adding it back in is going to introduce untold amounts of pain in the future for sure.

Comment: Have you search all the filed in the install for the column name? Should quickly get you to the problem code... Probably in an addon that needs updating.

Comment: Unfortunately that was part of my standard troubleshooting. I have an empty third_party folder right now, I uninstalled everything other than the channel module, all extensions and plugins gone. I just have an empty EE install, all that remains is all the original entries and the template code above. I've grepped the EE files for dst_enabled but doesn't appear anywhere, which is kinda expected. This one I tell you is totally weird. Think it's a job for EllisLab to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay pinned this one down, it made no sense for good reason.

We were running the staging site out of the same hosting account as the live site, which should have been fine. But due to a misconfiguration, any SSL pages were being loaded from the live site but as we load the DB based on the hostname, it was still pulling the stage DB.

As only some pages enforced SSL that's why the problems were intermittent, and only when we access the pages over SSL did it pull the 2.5.5 files instead.